# docker build non-root USER results in permission denied for /dev/stdout

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have a `Dockerfile` that successfully runs many RUN steps as root. It then successfully adds a user via `useradd`. I then want to run commands as that user. As far as I understand it, that is the purpose of [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user). However, when `docker build` spins up a container as that USER for the subsequent RUN step, I get the following `/dev/stdout` permission denied failure:

```
 ---> Running in 4b62b45b7405
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to setup user: chown /dev/stdout: permission denied: unknown
```

I'm running on a `CentOS 7` host.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem on my system:

```
FROM centos:7

ARG username

RUN useradd \
    --home-dir /home/$username \
    --gid users \
    --shell /bin/bash \
    --create-home \
    $username

WORKDIR /home/$username
USER $username

# Any RUN command as USER $username seems to fail.
RUN touch /tmp/d
```

Note that the touch command should be pretty innocuous, and shouldn't even try to write to stdout (I assume). Yet I get the following error when running `docker build` with this `Dockerfile`:

```
╰─➤  docker build --tag deleteme --build-arg username=bneradt .                                                                                                                                                   
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : FROM centos:7
 ---> eeb6ee3f44bd
Step 2/6 : ARG username
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8959f85f143c
Step 3/6 : RUN useradd     --home-dir /home/$username     --gid users     --shell /bin/bash     --create-home     $username
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60ede7eea71a
Step 4/6 : WORKDIR /home/$username
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 55255db14c51
Step 5/6 : USER $username
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4feac8162035
Step 6/6 : RUN touch /tmp/d
 ---> Running in 2fdbfdf266e7
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to setup user: chown /dev/stdout: permission denied: unknown
```

I seem to be running a recent version of docker (at the time of posting this):

```
╰─➤  docker --version                                          
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

I assume something simple has to be wrong. Maybe something with my tty permissions on my host? The `USER` feature seems so basic, so I assume it shouldn't always be broken for any command as it seems to be for my environment. Can someone help me to get this to work?

### Work Around

I have currently worked around the issue by putting all of my user-specific commands in a script file called `configure_user`, `COPY`'ing that into the container in the Dockerfile, then `RUN`'ing the script. Thus:

```
COPY configure_user /tmp
RUN su $username -c "bash /tmp/configure_user $git_username $git_email"
```

That works around the issue, but is unfortunate. It makes it so that the commands aren't broken down via `RUN` commands with intervening docker images at each step. I would still prefer a solution to the `/dev/stdout` permissions issue if anyone knows of one.

Comment: Are you sure the `arg` you pass in as well as the initial `RUN` command is making the correct user you expect and adding it to the group?

Comment: @ViaTech: Seems to be. If I run `docker run -it 60ede7eea71a --name inspect_user /bin/bash`, I can see the user's home directory and that the directories belong to the `users` group. In fact, I can run any command I want after doing a `run` on the base image for those docker build container intermediate steps. I'm not sure why the `docker build` process itself is having troubles.

Comment: That Dockerfile runs successfully for me, provided I remember to pass a `docker build --build-arg` option.  Do you have better results if you remove the `ARG` and use a fixed name for your user?  It shouldn't have any real effect on the program's operation.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? If so have you tried putting it into permissive mode and running the build? I just ran into the same issue and SELinux was causing this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for docker build :

```
 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...
```

and, for docker-compose :

```
 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose up --build ...
```